# Adding padding above menu

Tags: menus, css, formatting

I am not sure why but after I done some editing the menu now has no space from the type of the page. How do I create this ?

http://croiativefilms.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum is specific to WordPress internal workaround and your question is regarding element styling which does not belong here. Please try to use specific sites according to your question.

For your problem, add the following lines in your theme's stylesheet and it should be fixed.

```
#masthead #cms-header.header-ontop {
    padding-top:15px;
}

#masthead #cms-header.header-sticky {
    padding-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Sid. Where do I find this forum?

Comment: First, you need to try solving the problem by urself and then post it on StackOverflow with the code you tried.

Comment: ping me on vitthaldas.siddharth@gmail.com 
I have some more suggestions for the website